# Does Multi-Network wordpress takes 2 wordpress resource or 1 wordpress resource

Tags: wordpress

We know wordpress has multi-network option.

I wanted to know, whether creating multi-network wordpress, does it takes resource equal to 2 wordpress , when we create 2 network, or the resources used is 1 , only database tables are 2 ?

If so, yes, does that mean, if some one creates 5 multi-network wordpress site, it will still have 1 wordpress installed with 4 database tables for each 1 wordpress table ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, In wordpress multi-site network, there will be only 1 wordpress installation being used but although there will be different database tables.

**For example**

For 6 multisite network :

Wordpress Installation => 1

Database tables => There will be some common tables like `wp_users`, `wp_usermeta`, `wp_sites`, `wp_blogs` etc and all other tables will be different for each site within network.

**UPDATE**

No matter how many sites you have inside your multisite network, it is still going to use a single database instead of creating each new database for every single site and this also gives you more ease to manage your site database.

For every new site WordPress multisite will create bunch of new tables inside the same database, to make sure no site collide with each other.

Generally the primary site uses the table prefix provided by you during the installation, e.g. `gkv_` and for every new site after that inside your network, the table prefix is going to be increased by 1 for every new site like `gkv1_`, `gkv2_` and so on. Also most of the WordPress specific objects inside your server is also going to be initialized once for all of your sites as you are using a single instance of WordPress as multisite network.

In short it reduces a lot of resources rather than using 50 different single installations.

For more details : https://www.isaumya.com/advantages-of-wordpress-multisite-how-to-create-one/

Comment: Resource usage will also be equal to 1 wordpress installation or resource usage will be equal to 6 wordpress installation ??